# Call Custom REST API When Refreshing Access Token

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I have a custom sign-in policy that calls a custom REST API that fetches some information about the user from my database.

That information needs to be updated every once in a while, but I can afford to update it once an hour.

The problem is, that we don't prompt the user to login every hour. Instead, we refresh the token silently every hour with `acquireTokenSilent`

I need to somehow intercept the `acquireTokenSilent`, to make it call my custom REST API and pull the additional claims, just like I do it in the custom sign-in policy.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: What kind of app you working on? SPA or MVC or something else?

Comment: @Ramakrishna I have an SPA (angular) that calls a ASP.NET Core Web API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The **Configure the resource owner password credentials flow in Azure Active Directory B2C using a custom policy** article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/ropc-custom) describes how you can implement a user journey for the token refresh.

Specifically:

1. This user journey is referred to from the **RefreshTokenUserJourneyId** metaproperty of the **JwtIssuer** technical profile.

```xml
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>Token Issuer</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="JwtIssuer">
      <Metadata>
        <!-- Point to the redeem refresh token user journey-->
        <Item Key="RefreshTokenUserJourneyId">ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentials-RedeemRefreshToken</Item>
      </Metadata>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

2. The **ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentials-RedeemRefreshToken** user journey checks whether the refresh token has been invalidated.

```xml
<UserJourney Id="ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentials-RedeemRefreshToken">
  <PreserveOriginalAssertion>false</PreserveOriginalAssertion>
  <OrchestrationSteps>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="RefreshTokenSetupExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SM-RefreshTokenReadAndSetup" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="CheckRefreshTokenDateFromAadExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId-CheckRefreshTokenDate" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
  </OrchestrationSteps>
</UserJourney>
```

You can add your API call to this user journey.

Comment: I tried this but adding additional claims in here do not refresh claims passed in access token. Did you had any luck testing this ? Also looked at your other answer without any luck - > https://stackoverflow.com/a/49603509/1371639

Comment: Anyone got this to work?  I have the same problem as @Karthik...  no update claims in access token after REST call added to journey.  Like adding a break point shows it fires, just token doesn't have the changes.

Comment: @TimHarker - When I did this last year - There is no way we can refresh claims with  the out-of-box B2C setup. You need to raise a request with Microsoft to enable this feature for your Azure AD Tenant (they do some magic in the backend for you).

Comment: Any updates on this? I've implemented it and experiencing the same behaviour. When I perform a token refresh I can see it hits my REST endpoint and the UserJourneyRecorder shows the updated claim value, however the id_token returned to the client still reflects the old value.

Answer (score 1):

**Check @Chris Padgett answer**

One way you can achieve like,

1. Put a timer to make a web API call (I guess you already have one to raise silent renew request)
2. Make a [Authorize] rest API call from JS by sending user access token
3. Make a DB Call to pull the details from rest API and save them in your SPA app local variables.

Comment: 1. Actually, I call `acquireTokenSilent` prior to every request. The method automatically refreshes the token if it's expired. 2. If I store the additional claim in the client, then the server would have to verify them every request, that's what I want to avoid by storing them inside the token.