# Scope "scp" missing when Requesting a token in Azure AD B2C

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c

So I am trying to protect a web API using Azure AD B2C but when I try to access an endpoint with the token obtained using "Run user flow" I get the following exception:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: IDW10201: Neither scope or roles
> claim was found in the bearer token.

**My Code:**

I created a new ASP.NET Core App and used the dialog to add authentication automatically.

Some interesting points in the code:

I tried added the following to the appsettings.json file and it didn't help:

```
"AllowWebApiToBeAuthorizedByACL": true
```

I tried removing this from the controller and it didn't help:

```
// The Web API will only accept tokens 1) for users, and 2) having the "access_as_user" scope for this API
static readonly string[] scopeRequiredByApi = new string[] { "access_as_user" };
HttpContext.VerifyUserHasAnyAcceptedScope(scopeRequiredByApi);
```

In ConfigureServices I have the following code:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"));
```

**Azure Portal:**

1. I created a new tenant for Azure AD B2C
2. I registered an application

[image: applicationcreated]

3. API Permissions

Here I have been playing a lot with it, those are the permissions I have enabled right now:

[image: https://i.ibb.co/DrV7fDv/permissions.png]

4. Create User flow

[image: https://i.ibb.co/sPj2BSK/userFlow.png]

Then when I run the user flow this is what I get:

Link used:

> https://xxxxxxxxxxx001.b2clogin.com/xxxxxxxxx001.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
>
> p=B2C_1_user_flow_test_signinsignup
>
> &client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxx
>
> &nonce=defaultNonce
>
> &redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fjwt.ms
>
> &scope=openid
>
> &response_type=id_token
>
> &prompt=login

[image: token]

I am completely new to azure and after researching the whole internet I can't figure out what is the issue here, and why scp is not in the token I obtain when running the user flow from the link provided in azure portal.

I would really appreciate in help in what I am missing to set up or what I have set up wrongly.

Comment: Are you calling Azure-protected api or MS graph api?

Comment: I am using the feature "Run User Flow" from Azure portal. Basically it just provides a link which is the following: https://mytenant.b2clogin.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_user_flow_test_signinsignup&client_id=myclientId&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fjwt.ms&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are getting is the id token. There is no `scp` claim for the id token. It only contains the information of the logged-in user. What you are performing is only the logged-in user's operation.

If you want to get `scp` claims, you should [request an access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/access-tokens) instead of a id token.

Comment: In the POST operation to get the token, I am trying to execute it with Postman and curl and whatever I try it I get "could not resolve the host". What it is the recommended scenario for developers get the token and test the API?

Comment: Just in case it helps someone, I managed to get the token using Postman with the help of this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47275079/request-access-token-in-postman-for-azure-ad-b2c Also, what I was missing was to create my API scopes and grant them permissions. Thanks a lot Carl, your answers here and in other posts of different users were very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the Carl answer, With the use of B2C link you'll only get an ID token as it sets the response type to id_token, just like the article states. In order to get an access token your response_type field needs to be 'response_type=code' or 'response_type=code+id_token' and even then JWT.ms wont show it. if you capture a dev tools network trace you'll see two parameters in the authresp frame access_token and id_token. decoding the access_token with jwt.io will show us what you are looking for.