# how to Get token from URL?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, token, azure-ad-b2c

My ADB2C created login page redirects to SPA after successful authentication and has an access token as URL parameter in the redirect URL.
First, I want to extract an access token from a URL. Is this possible?
And second, I want to store the extracted access token in localstorage. Is this also possible?
Once these two are in place, I would expect the SPA to be able to access the backend API using an access token.
thank you.

Comment: You should rely on the client libraries like `msal.js` or `msal-angular` [based on your client side framework], rather than you trying to access or store the token yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get ***access token*** from URL make use of [Postman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/installation-and-updates/).

- In Postman, Open & switch to Authorization tab
- Select `OAuth 2.0` from the **Type** dropdown
- In Grant type dropdown, select Authorization Code
- In callback Url, enter your redirect Url
- In Auth Url, enter your Authorize Url
- In Access toke Url, enter your token Url
- Enter your client ID and enter scope.
- click the ***Get New Access Token*** button.
- And this will ***generate access token.***

For more in detail, please refer these ***links:***

[Obtaining an Access Token from Azure B2C using OAuth2.0 Authorization Code with PKCE in POSTMAN (vmsdurano.com)](https://vmsdurano.com/requesting-access-token-from-azure-b2c-with-pkce-using-postman/#:%7E:text=Enter%20the%20Authorize%20Url%20as%20the%20Auth%20URL.,with%20your%20Azure%20AD%20B2c%20username%20and%20password.).

[Request Access Token in Postman for Azure AD B2C - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47275079/request-access-token-in-postman-for-azure-ad-b2c).